# I want pass two payloads and variables data inside the VM in mule 3.4.2.How I need to pass them?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

I want pass two payloads and variables data inside the VM in mule 3.4.2. How can I pass this data?

Comment: u should show your efforts first and then ask for help regarding any errors.

Comment: Explain two? two separate messages? or do you want to separate one message into two? or parallell multicast the same message to two VM endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

By definition a message has only one payload. Perhaps what you are looking for is [attachments](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Attachment+Transformer+Reference)?

Answer (score 0):

In Mule you can't have two payloads at same time. Rather you can Store your payload into Session variable and pass Variables into your flow VM.

Comment: without using session variables . is there any way to store?